# Resizing gif images

Tags: image, graphics

I have a gif image 720 * 40 pixels used as a footer on a website. I need to extend the height of the gif by 10 pixels. I was unable to resize to this, using Office Picture Manager. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: This belongs on SuperUser.com, as it is not programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an image editor such a photoshop or gimp or paint.net.

Create a new image sized 730 * 40 and paste your original to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try an online solution like [this](http://www.pixlr.com/)